# How to OR and AND operator in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I need to `OR` and `AND` operator while expression evaluation, but when I use it to `CLIPSDOS` it give wrong result.

```
CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> ( and 0 1 )
TRUE
CLIPS>
```

I expect the output `FALSE` but it give `TRUE`
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, the integer 0 is false and any other integer is true.

In CLIPS, the symbol FALSE is false and any other value is true.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (and 0 1)
TRUE
CLIPS> (and 1 2)
TRUE
CLIPS> (and FALSE TRUE)
FALSE
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks above solution worked.
Below code also worked


CLIPS> ( or ( > 0 0 ) ( > 3 3 ) ) 
FALSE
CLIPS>